# What is an APA-certified editor?

Tags: editing, academic-writing, apa

Is APA-certified editor an actual credential?

If yes, is there a universally-accepted proof in the U.S. for that credential?

I tried a web search on "how to become an APA-certified editor." I clicked through four pages of the hits where the bulk of the references were about obtaining PhDs or APA licensing.

The hits I did find were for a few people advertising their services for APA-style editing, and one reference to an APA editing workshop.

I'm interested in (maybe) editing dissertations for doctoral students at small for-profit universities (not editing journals).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am almost entirely certain that no such thing exists as an actual credential from the APA directly.  However, I would imagine that some programs, maybe at the community college level or other certifying bodies, may offer a certificate as an APA-style editor (or any other style).

I have a four-year degree in writing and rhetoric, and the track I was in was Writing as a Discipline which would most closely align with something like this, and still no...  no certification (granted my school was primarily an MLA shop, but there was no MLA-certified editor option, either).

Remember that, given the desire and options, you can become "certified" in almost anything.  Johnny's Certification Shack could offer you a cert in APA-style editing.  That doesn't mean that anyone, especially the APA, would be impressed.

Comment: Some of the universities require a signed form such as "The <title> dissertation by <student name> is in compliance with <name of style and formatting publication>. / Signed by APA Style Editor Name ____  ~~ Based on your reply, Jesse, I can see that having a certification per se is perhaps not necessary.